# Снимок окна с тенью в OSX Yosimite

Tags: macos, apple

Пишу документацию по OSX приложения, в документации много снимков окон.

Снимки делаю через стандартное приложение "Снимок экрана" (`Grab`). В Mavericks при снимке окна накладывалась красивая тень, после обновления до Yosimite тень пропала.

Нагуглил команду:

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture disable-shadow -bool false
killall SystemUIServer
```

Не помогло. Как вернуть тень или есть альтернативы `Grab`, которые умеют делать снимки с тенью?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалась странная бага, тень не появляется если вызывать команду снимка из меню программы Grab, но при этом тень есть при создании снимка через сочетание клавиш cmd+shift+4+space

Comment: Возможно, что тень есть только у активного окна, а при запуске через меню, окно не активно (просто предположение)